# How to let IBM BlueSocket run on a GUI application and support multi connections

Tags: swift, sockets

Recently, I found a pure swift socket server and client called IBM [BlueSocket](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket). 
It is suitable for me that it does server-cleint communication.
It has a pretty simple sample. but I encountered some problems. 
1. How to run it on a GUI application's run loop?
2. How to run it and support multi connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample has been recently updated and illustrates use of the GCD based Dispatch API to do multi-threading and supporting multiple connections. It also should give you a idea on how to run it on the main queue (which'll work for either a GUI or server application).

Comment: To Bill Abt: Thanks for your great and simple sample.

Comment: See simple-minded chat client program below, that I used as "proof of concept" to ensure BlueSocket runs OK under iOS and to get a feel for how one interfaces with it.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I present the world's simplest chat client.

```
import Foundation
import Socket

// Very simplified chat client for BlueSocket - no UI, it just connects to the echo server, 
// exchanges a couple of messages and then disconnects.
// You can run two instances of Xcode on your Mac, with the BlueSocketEchoServer running in one and 
// this program running in the other. It has been tested running in the iPhone simulator, i.e., 
// under iOS, without problems.
// License: Public domain.
public class BlueSocketChatClient {

   public func runClient() {

      do {
         let chatSocket = try Socket.create(family: .inet6)

         try chatSocket.connect(to: "127.0.0.1", port: 1337)

         print("Connected to: \(chatSocket.remoteHostname) on port \(chatSocket.remotePort)")

         try readFromServer(chatSocket)

         try chatSocket.write(from: "Hello to you too!")

         try readFromServer(chatSocket)

         try chatSocket.write(from: "Bye now!\n")
         try chatSocket.write(from: "QUIT")

         sleep(1)  // Be nice to the server
         chatSocket.close()
      }
      catch {
         guard let socketError = error as? Socket.Error else {
            print("Unexpected error ...")
            return
         }
         print("Error reported:\n \(socketError.description)")
      }
   }


   // This is very simple-minded. It blocks until there is input, and it then assumes that all the 
   // relevant input has been read in one go.
   func readFromServer(_ chatSocket : Socket) throws {
      var readData = Data(capacity: chatSocket.readBufferSize)
      let bytesRead = try chatSocket.read(into: &readData)
      guard bytesRead > 0 else {
         print("Zero bytes read.")
         return
      }
      guard let response = String(data: readData, encoding: .utf8) else {
         print("Error decoding response ...")
         return
      }
      print(response)
   }
}
```

Bill Abt: If you can use this in any way you're welcome to it.